# Listing all files in a folder with added sentences in between each file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, I currently have a simple batch file using dir to list all the file names in a folder:

```
dir /b > FileList.txt
```

But I also want to append information in-between each line, namely the full path to the file, so it'd look like this.

```
File1.doc
C:\Path\File1.doc
File2.doc
C:\Path\File2.doc
```

Could you suggest an effective way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to get all files and then write what you want to a FileList.txt. Please note that the double percent sign is needed in a batch file but not in an interactive cmd.exe (where only one percent sign is needed).

```
del FileList.txt
for /D %%i in (*) do (
  echo %%i >>FileList.txt
  echo %%~fi >>FileList.txt
)
```